# Can you call an external application from a Windows 10 Universal application? c#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have been working on a Minecraft server wrapper for the past week. I was looking forward to making a windows 10 universal app, but in my learning and testing I discovered that System.Diagnostics.Process is not supported in windows 8 store apps. When trying to add the code to my Win 10 dev machine in a 10 project I am being told that it cant be resolved.

Is there going to be a way to launch an external process and capture the output into a textbox with Win10 Universal apps or am I out of luck?

Comment: No, that's not possible. What are you trying to do with a server-in-an-app?

Comment: A server management tool. Or wrapper. Help with the setup of the server, run it. . back it up. . even some basic user management from the app.

Answer (score 4):

Your target app will need to support app services to do this. It isn't possible to launch and control arbitrary apps. If the target app is designed as an app service then you can launch and communicate it with Launcher.[LaunchUriForResultsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn956687.aspx)

For more on app services see the Build session [App-to-App Communication: Building a Web of Apps](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-765)

Comment: Thanks Rob. I will look into that. I can only hope that since MS purchased Minecraft that they will roll this into the app jars. Otherwise it can communicate with the server via RCON and Query. But then launching the server might be tricky. Unless it is possible to write an app service that's sole job is to launch the jar file.

Comment: so there is no way to run a cmd line program from a Win 10 universal app?