# How to open exe application inside of the UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, view, uwp, exe

Is there any solution how to open exe file (as for me as example it's Flash app and Prezi.exe) in view in the UWP app?

Something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6GWgxEvibE

Comment: Not directly, but if the target app is an app service you can, please [**see**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30493073/1797425) more there.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? The video is 19min long, it's not clear what exactly you want to accomplish. Host Flash in a UWP app window? Or something else ...

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t provided enough information. My exe apps contain flash presentations, so it’s just necessary to find a mechanism of launching exe file in UWP

Comment: @АнтонИванник It's impossible. It's not supported to open exe application as a children window in UWP.